# animateWithDuration doesn't properly run when in NSOperation completionBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation

I'm trying to download a file with the 3rd party library `AFNetworking`,
At its core there is an `NSOperation` object for which one can set a completion block, for when the download has finished.

Somehow, an `animateWithDuration:` within this block doesn't run properly: Both it's completion block and actual animation are delayed by either ~ 5 or 60 seconds or don't run at all. The only way to know that it starts at all is via a NSLog call.

Let me demonstrate it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
    animations:^{
        controller.view.alpha=0.5;
        NSLog(@"First Try Start");
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"First Try End");
}];


// Here comes the NSOperation completion block
[self->currentConnection setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
            animations:^{
                controller.view.alpha=0.5; // this doesn't run immediately, only the NSLog line
                NSLog(@"Second Try Start");
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Second Try End");
    }];
}];
```

Console output:

```
2013-06-28 23:22:11.374 ML[7831:c07] First Try Start
2013-06-28 23:22:11.477 ML[7831:c07] First Try End
2013-06-28 23:22:11.742 ML[7831:1303] downloadComplete!
2013-06-28 23:22:11.745 ML[7831:1303] Second Try Start
2013-06-28 23:23:05.007 ML[7831:c07] Second Try End
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIKit is not especially thread-safe. Manipulating UIKit objects in threads other than the main thread will cause unpredictable results, mostly in the form of objects not visibly responding to changes in state.

You can use GCD in your completion block to schedule a block to run on the main thread:

```
[self->currentConnection setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
            animations:^{
                    controller.view.alpha=0.5;
                    NSLog(@"Second Try Start");
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished
                NSLog(@"Second Try End");
            }
        ];
    });
}];
```

Comment: While I still don't really understand why it didn't work in the first place, I know where you're coming from and most importantly, your suggested fix works! Thanks.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time.  One thing to note is that with Xcode 5 I was required to remove the "void". dispatch_get_main_queue(); worked for me.

Comment: That must have been a copy-and-paste artifact.  I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

// define following method in your's class

```
-(void)updateView:(UIView *)paramView {
   paramView = 0.5
}
```

// And call following line of code in place where you set controller.alpha = 0.5
// As now you are updating alpha on main thread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateView:)  withObject:controller.view waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: I clearly need to run this line within a callback function. As far as I know, there's no other way to get notified about when the network request is done.